# vjsf.js library: Display form field dynamically based on selected value from another field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using **vjsf** library for vue.js form (https://koumoul-dev.github.io/vuetify-jsonschema-form/latest/). I am trying to display one of the fields of the form dynamically: **memberStatusChange** should only display when specific value of select **callDisposition** was selected. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I was hoping for any pointers how to achieve this functionality. Forms schema is bellow. Thank you

```
{
                "id": "https://test.com",
                "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
                "description2": "MemberPrequalification",
                "type": "object",
                "required": [             
                   "callDisposition"
                ],

                "properties": {

                   "callDisposition": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "title": "Call Disposition",
                      "x-summary": true,
                      "x-display": "custom-component",
                      "enum": [
                         "Did not call",
                         "Engaged - Callback Requested - Snoozed",
                         "Engaged - Completed",
                         "Engaged - Not Completed",
                         "Engaged - No Action Needed",
                         "Engaged - Member Declined"

                      ]
                   },
                   "memberStatusChange": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "title": "Member Status Change",
                      "x-if": "parent.value.callDisposition?.toString() === 'Engaged - Completed'",
                      "x-display": "custom-component",
                      "enum": [
                         "Agreed",
                         "Declined",
                         "Ineligible - Medical Criteria",
                         "Ineligible - Coverage",
                         "Deceased"
                      ]
                   }

                }
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this workaround instead of using library build-in functionality: could not figure out how to use x-if dynamically based on value of another input. I ended up attaching function to input value

Added displayStatus() to change event:

```
                <v-jsf
                  :disabled="context.disabled"
                  :model-key="context.modelKey"
                  :options="evaluateOptions(context)"
                  :required="context.required"
                  :rules="context.rules"
                  :schema="JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(context.schema))"
                  :value="context.value"
                  @change="displayStatus"
                  @input="context.on.input">
              </v-jsf>
```

Options values:

```
     options: {
        context: {
           displayStatus: false,
           memberStatusChangeActive: "Completed"
        },
        summary: false,
        disableAll: false,
        markdownit: {
           html: true
        }
     }
```

Schema:

```
 {
                  "id": "https://test.com",
                  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
                  "description2": "MemberPrequalification",
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                     "callDisposition": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "title": "Call Disposition",
                        "x-summary": true,
                        "x-display": "custom-component",
                        "enum": [
                           "Did not call",
                           "Engaged - Callback Requested - Snoozed",
                           "Completed"       
                        ]
                     },
                     "memberStatusChange": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "x-summary": true,
                        "title": "Member Status Change",
                        "x-if": "context.displayStatus",
                        "enum": [
                           "Agreed",
                           "Declined"                      
                        ]
                     }
                  }
             }
```

Function:

```
   methods: {
             displayStatus() {
                if (typeof this.form.callDisposition != "undefined"
                    && this.form.callDisposition === this.options.context.memberStatusChangeActive) {
                   this.options.context.displayStatus = true;
                } else if (typeof this.form.callDisposition != "undefined"
                           && this.form.callDisposition !== this.options.context.memberStatusChangeActive) {
                   this.options.context.displayStatus = false;
                }
             }
           }
```